# Callback from angular.js service is a promise, but I need the data.

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('NodeService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  'use strict';
  ...
      JMSStats:{
           url: "/some/restUrl",
           method: 'GET',
           isArray: true,
      },
  ....
```

and in my controller

```
NodeService.JMSStats({ id: nodeId }, function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

the data looks like it is a promise rather than the actual data. That is fine and makes sense, but I have to use that data here in the controller.

How can I set it to have a callback of some sort for when the data resolves?

I tried something like this:

```
data.$promise.finally(function(){
    console.log(data);
  });
```

but data still is set to the promise.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
data.$promise.then(function(d){
    console.log(d);
  });
```